# Magento 2.1 data migration SUPER privilege error

Tags: magento2, database, migration, magento2-migration-tool

When running the data migration tool

```
php bin/magento migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.0/config.xml
```

We get the following error:

**[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1419 You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable), query was: CREATE  
   TRIGGER trg_catalog_compare_item_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_compare_item FOR EACH ROW                                                                                                            
  BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  INSERT INTO m2_cl_catalog_compare_item (`catalog_compare_item_id`, `operation`) VALUES (NEW.catalog_compare_item_id, 'INSERT')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operation = 'INSERT';                                 
  END
```

Unfortunately, as we are on a **Shared Server** they cannot provide this privilege or configure this variable from the hosting's end.

Is there something we can change to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the privilage of your db username in the server backend (CPanel or anything else? Does it includes trigger? Have you tried to run this in shell : 

mysql -u USERNAME -p (your password) and then run 

set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;

Answer (score 3):

You may try to set the MySQL variable directly on the MySQL client.

```
set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

> If not, you need to check with your hosting provider.

Comment: Unfortunately this also requires SUPER privileges. I was thinking that there might be a way to configure or modify the migrator to AVOID requiring these SUPER privileges

Comment: You can try this workaround. Disable the trigger during migration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480074/mysql-disable-all-triggers or http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-disableenable-triggers-on-demand.html

Comment: But side effects may occurs. You may try to migrate your database in a local environment, then reimport your data with mysql dump